# Как боту Телеграмм на библиотеке aiogram 3.х открыть текстовый файл на чтение из чата Телеграм без сохранения его на жесткий диск

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Прoсьбa пoомoчь нaйти решение крaйне вaжной функции ботa.

Есть чaт в телеграмме с ботом на aiogram 3. Когда туда попадает текстовый файл (txt, json и пр.), бот видит файл, должен загрузить его и открыть на чтение и далее проводить с ним всякие операции. Главное условие: он не должен охранять его на жесткий диск, можно либо в оперативную память, либо как-то на сервер телеги. В общем что угодно, но диск не трогать.

```
@dp message.register(get_file, F.document.file_name.startswith('uvedomlenie_n'))
async def get_file(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await message.answer('json - файл перехватил')
    json_file_id = message.document.file_id
    json_file_name = message.document.file_name
    json_file = await bot.get_file(message.document.file_id) # это загрузит файл по его id
```

Далее по классике он сохраняется на диск и потом уже открывается на чтение и работается с ним. Но мне нельзя его сохранять, только сразу открыть и работать с ним. КАК это сделать?

Comment: Также просьба помочь с формированием и отправкой текстового файла. Т.е. бот создает текстовый файл и в текущем состоянии он сохраняет файл на диск, а потом уже отправляет его в чат или пользователю. Необходимо сформировать и отправить файл без сохранения на диск, можно в оперативку, сервак телеги, возможно даже подключение облака с открытым доступом.  Размер файла до 50 МБ.

Comment: Приглядитесь к модулю io.